# Stored procedure setting a value if row is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How would I go about setting a value if a row is empty ('')?

I was thinking something like,

Got var with default value called @defaultValue to set it where the row in a table is ''.

```
if (select col1 from table1 where col1 = '')
set (select col1 from table1 where col1 = '') = @DefaultValue
```

is there a better way?

code is just a draft its not even tested..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the table with `@DefaultValue`, you can use `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET col1=@DefaultValue
WHERE col1=''
   OR col1 IS NULL
```

**OR**

If you are trying to select `@DefaultValue` if the column is empty or null, you can do this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (col1 IS NULL OR col1='') 
              THEN @DefaultValue
              ELSE col1
            END AS Col1
FROM table1
```

Comment: True, is it possible to have an Update in a If-statement? Kind of makes it easier to read for other using it, hence the question.

Comment: @SterlinkArcher: Why do you want to use an if-statement in an update query. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @SterlinkArcher: What idea? Can you tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when col1 ='' then @DefaultValues else col1 end from table
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17735)

```
declare @default int
set @default=1

declare @tbl table(col1 int)
insert into @tbl values(1),(''),(2)

select case when col1='' or col1 is null then @default else col1 end from @tbl
```